# Accessing struct and union member functions within a class

Tags: c++, struct, unions

In this program I just want to test a structure and union within a class itself.

I had created a public `struct`, and declared a union within it.

I am using Visual Studio and Qt Creator to type this code.

I want to ask, is defining a `struct` within a class good and accessible?
I am having problem with that.

If this is correct, how could I access the method or data member of the `struct` from `main`?

I'd also like to use the `union` member of the `struct`.

If the method or functions of the `struct` are not accessible this way,. what's another way of doing it?

//************************************************************************************

```
#ifndef CTEST_H
#define CTEST_H

class CTest {
    int value;
public:
    CTest(int);
    int getValue();
    struct CTESTSTRUCT {
        union CTESTUNION
        {
            enum CTestEnum {
                var1 = 1
            };
            char varChar1 = 'Y';
            char varChar2 /*= 'N'*/; //union atmost have one field initializer
        };
        int structValue();
        int testVal;
    };
    ~CTest();
};

#endif

//************************************************************************************

#include <iostream>
#include "CTest.h"

CTest::CTest(int argVal) : value(argVal) {
    std::cout << "Constructor Called" << std::endl;
}

int CTest::getValue() {
    std::cout << "getValue Called" << std::endl;
    return value;
}

int CTest::CTESTSTRUCT::structValue() {
    std::cout << "CTESTSTRUCT::setValue Called" << std::endl;
    return CTESTSTRUCT::CTESTUNION::var1;
}

CTest::~CTest() {
    std::cout << "Distructor Called" << std::endl;
}

//*********************************************************************************

#include <iostream>
#include "CTest.h"

using namespace std;

CTest * ctestObj;

int main() {


    ctestObj = new CTest(25);
    int returnVal = ctestObj->getValue();
    std::cout << "Value Returned: " << returnVal << std::endl;
    std::cout << "structVal: " << std::endl;
    //CTest::CTESTSTRUCT::testVal = 10;
    delete ctestObj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're actually trying to do is have an **instance** of a struct inside your class. What you did was define a class within your class (which did not actually give your class a member of that type, but only scoped its definition).

So what you need to do is pull our the `struct`, from the class:

```
struct CTESTSTRUCT
{
   // ...
};
```

And then give `CTest` a member of type `CTESTSTRUCT`

```
class CTest {
    int value;
public:
    CTest(int);
    int getValue();
    CTESTSTRUCT test;

    ~CTest();
};
```

Now you can access it like so:

```
int main() {
    CTest * ctestObj;
    ctestObj = new CTest(25);
    int returnVal = ctestObj->getValue();
    std::cout << "Value Returned: " << returnVal << std::endl;
    std::cout << "structVal: " << std::endl;
    ctestObj->test.testVal = 10;
    delete ctestObj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't *have* to pull the definitions out of CTest, it's just probably what he wants to do.

Comment: Also, downvote for using new when a local variable would have been perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @kfsone: I preserved OPs other code, which included new/delete. I think a downvote is a bit harsh for that, but c'est la vie.

Comment: @kfsone: Re: your first comment. OP doesn't technically have to, yes. Technically all they need is a member of that type. However, it appears that they were simply confused about how to get another user defined class object within another one, and approached it the way they did. Pulling it out makes the most sense.